# How to know when Redshift UNLOAD finishes

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, boto3, psycopg2

I'm doing a script to perform UNLOAD action through psycopg2. the script will put the file in S3 bucket and when it finishes I need to download it. 
I want to know if there's any way to be notified to can start to download the file(s). I explored the option of activate S3 notifications but since is bucket used by other services this could not be the approach .

code looks like

```
q = """ unload ('select * from foo')
to 's3://mybucket/'  iam_role 'MYROLE' CSV parallel off;
"""

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(q)
    # ...
    # know when process finishes here 
    # ...
    # download the file(s) created by UNLOAD
    s3.meta.client.download_file('mybucket', 'file_000', '/tmp/file_000.txt')
    cursor.close()
```

Comment: I can't see any notification capability provided by Amazon Redshift. I presume the `execute()` would return once the operation is complete. Is that not what you are experiencing?

Comment: You're right, since I couldn't  test on my local env. I was investigating how redshift treats the UNLOAD action.
and the service is blocked until execute() finishes and it means that all the files was created.

Comment: [I think this answer by John Rotenstein](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61966008/how-to-know-when-redshift-unload-finishes/73948619#comment109600140_61966008) is correct. You do not need to do a check.

But if you need to monitor the output of the job for some reason, like observing from somewhere else you can check `stl_unload_log`:

```sql
select *
from stl_unload_log
where path like 's3://<your output prefix>/%'
and end_time is not null
and start_time > "your_started_date"
order by start_time desc;
```